# How do you filter by custom attribute in GetCandy?

Tags: laravel, getcandy

How do you filter by custom attribute in GetCandy?

I'm trying to filter search results on a GetCandy website, currently, I am using the API like so:

```
/api/v1/search?brand=hasbro&type=product
```

but it seems to still be giving me back all the results, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the query string is correct, for a custom attribute to be filterable you need to make sure it's got `filterable` checked in the `attributes` table.

Also, when you make changes to attributes you may need to re-run

```
php artisan candy:search:index
```

Just because there are potential changes to the index mapping and currently with Elasticsearch you can't update this on an existing index.